# file upload error using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, file, upload

I am tryin to upload file in mysql database using php with codeigniter framework.
Following my code. Its just saving first name of file in database but actual file in not storing at the given path.

My code is -

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"] , "uploads/diagnosis_report/".$_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);          

$data['file_name'] = $_POST["userfile"]["name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe:

```
$data['file_name'] = $_POST["userfile"]["name"];
```

Should be:

```
$data['file_name'] = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
// ---------------------^
```

Comment: not working...! file_name in db showing value as NULL

Answer (score 0):

$upload_path`$_POST["userfile"]["name"]` is just the file name. If you want to save it with the path you need to do something like this:

```
// For relative path
$data['file_name'] = "uploads/diagnosis_report/".$_FILES["userfile"]["name"];

// For absolute path
$data['file_name'] = dirname(__FILE__)."/uploads/diagnosis_report/".$_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
```

Honestly what I would do is set an upload path variable first like so:

```
$upload_path = dirname(__FILE__)."/uploads/diagnosis_report/";
```

Then you can use it over and over again like so:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"] , $upload_path.$_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);          

$data['file_name'] = $upload_path.$_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
```

Hope this helps.